# MyBatis not working with Boolean mapping

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, persistence, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am just trying  to map a boolean value with Mybatis, but I am having a problem. Firstly, I'll show you the parts involved:

```
XML File:

<resultMap id="destinationTypeMap" type="DestinationTypeDTO">
        <result property="destinationTypeId" column="education_destination_type_id" javaType="java.lang.Long" jdbcType="NUMERIC"/>
        <result property="description" column="description" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
        <result property="available" column="is_available" javaType="boolean" jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="BooleanHandler"/>
    </resultMap>
```

Java class:

```
public class DestinationTypeDTO {

    private long destinationTypeId;
    private String description;
    private boolean available;

    public long getDestinationTypeId() {
        return destinationTypeId;
    }

    public void setDestinationTypeId(long destinationTypeId) {
        this.destinationTypeId = destinationTypeId;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        this.available = available;
    }

}
```

But, I am getting this error log:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set property 'isAvailable' of '....DestinationTypeDTO@bbd76bf' with value 'true' Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named 'isAvailable' in 'class ....DestinationTypeDTO'
```

I spent hours trying to find what's going on but without success. Any hint?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `javaType="boolean"` to `java.lang.Boolean` and specify `property="available"`

```
<result property="available" column="is_available" property="available" javaType="java.lang.Boolean" jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="BooleanHandler"/>
```

In your class change `private boolean available;` to `private Boolean isAvailable;` and add  getter/setter

```
public void setIsAvailable(Boolean available) {
    this.available = available;
}

public Boolean getIsAvailable() {
    return available;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but still not working mate. Any other suggestion?

Comment: infact boolean would just work as java treats it as primitve type

Comment: It doesn't works, please notice that property was "available" already before.

Comment: @stackpepe Could you try now

Comment: @stackpepe did you added both getter and setter?

Comment: Are your using Boolean and not boolean for the field?

Comment: Hi mate, your solution was right, the problem was that I didn't restart Weblogic so the xml files wasn't being reloaded. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
javaType="_boolean"
```

Not

```
javaType="boolean"
```

`_boolean` maps to `boolean`, `boolean` maps to `java.lang.Boolean`.

Documentation: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

Change your setter , ibatis expects boolean name with standard format of pojo:-

```
 public void setIsAvailable(boolean available) {
    this.available = available;
}
```

Comment: I did it but still not working. I am still getting this: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set property 'isAvailable' of 'uk.co.corelogic.mosaic.dto.education.DestinationTypeDTO@bbd76bf' with value 'true' Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named 'isAvailable' in 'class uk.co.corelogic.mosaic.dto.education.DestinationTypeDTO'

Answer (score 0):

Your database column is named "is_available" and your attribute is named "available" that's why the mapping is not working, you have two solutions for this:

1. Change the name of the column to "available" or change the name of the attribute"is_available"(not ok for Java)
2. In the sql query use "is_available as available".